# How to set Tag for whole view in RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview

This is reg. usage of setTag where I need to set  Tag for the View rather than individual items on the view in RecyclerView . I get data from DB  which I set in BindViewHolder . I need to set set for the View rather than individual items on View of each row . IS it possible to do so?

Comment: Why don't you just add the object to the viewholder? You don't need the 'tag'. I'm guessing you want the root view? Try `viewholder.itemView.setTag`

Comment: @David Medenjak that still doesn't work. It still gets the new position.